# Change project type

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have very big Java a project.
I want to change his type from java application to  plug-in project.
Is it possible? If yes, how?
thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to change nature in your .project file. ".project" file you can find in root directory of Project.
Change:

```
<natures>
    <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
</natures>
```

To:

```
<natures>
    <nature>org.eclipse.pde.PluginNature</nature>
    <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
</natures>
```

Answer (score 1):

Right click on your project -> Configure -> Convert to Plug-in Projects